# Why does the MKR WiFi 1010 LED_BUILTIN sometimes pulsate?

Tags: mkr1010

Sometimes the built-in LED pulsates after an upload. It could be after a failed upload but I'm not entirely sure. What does this indicate? I haven't been able to find any information about it.

It doesn't blink like in the Bliky example. It pulsates.

The led is not controlled by a Sketch. Usually this happens after a failed upload, and the previous Sketch doesn't work anymore.

Comment: maybe it is the sketch that you loaded

Comment: @jsotola Usually it's after a failed update, and my best guess is that it is, but I haven't seen it documented anywhere. It's not in the sketch.

Comment: bootloader does it while active